# Four brothers of different heights - confused over the answer

Tags: mathematics

The puzzle is this:

> Next door to me live four brothers of different heights. Their average height is 74 inches, and the difference in height among the first three men is two inches. The difference between the third and fourth man is six inches. Can you tell how tall is each brother?

Now, I got 78, 76, 74, and 68 as their respective heights, but the puzzle answer in the book  is 70, 74, 80, and 72. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In the book's answer there is only one height difference of 6" and that is between the 2nd and 3rd, not the 3rd and 4th which the puzzle states. So the book's answer makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question "Can you tell how tall is each brother?" is

> "No, it's impossible to tell; the 3rd guy is 74 inches tall though."

This is because

> the situation is ambiguous, and both your answer and the one in the book fit.

Since there is no mention if the first man is the shortest or the tallest one, the differences from the average are

> either -4, -2, 0, and 6 inches (book's answer) or the inverse, 4, 2, 0, and -6 (your answer).

Comment: I would say 1st: 75 2nd: 73 3rd: 71 4th: 77 and similar solutions are also valid, so It is a really bad question (unless your answer was the given one)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've interpreted the order of the men opposite from the book. You've ranked them from tallest to shortest, as opposed to shortest to tallest. Specifically, this has you group the first three as the three tallest, and the third and fourth as the second shortest and shortest, while the book does the reverse (first three as the three shortest, and the third and fourth as the second tallest and tallest).

The puzzle as stated is fairly ambiguous about the ordering, so it's a reasonable "mistake" to make

Comment: Only one of the heights is a correct answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you mind elaborating on your point?

Comment: I read your answer to mean that the list is reversed.

Comment: Ah, I see. I meant that they took "First man" to mean the tallest, while the book assumes the "First man" is the shortest. This assumption leads to different values (not just different order). I can clarify my answer